# Time since last event of grouped data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time

I have a data frame that contains a grouping variable (ID), a date and an event column with numeric values, in which 0 represent no event and >0 represents an event. An example data frame can be generated with the following code:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                   date = as.Date(c("2014-08-03", "2014-08-04", "2014-08-07", "2014-08-10", "2015-07-01", "2015-07-03", "2015-08-01")),
                   event = c(1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0))
df
> df
  ID       date event
1  1 2014-08-03     1
2  1 2014-08-04     0
3  1 2014-08-07     3
4  1 2014-08-10     0
5  2 2015-07-01     0
6  2 2015-07-03     4
7  2 2015-08-01     0
```

Now, I want to calculate the time that has passed since any last event (>0) has occured. In the particular case that the first entry/entries for any ID contains no event, "NA" should be generated. My desired output would look like this:

```
> df
  ID       date event tae
1  1 2014-08-03     1   0
2  1 2014-08-04     0   1
3  1 2014-08-07     3   0
4  1 2014-08-10     0   3
5  2 2015-07-01     0  NA
6  2 2015-07-03     4   0
7  2 2015-08-01     0  29
```

I have tried several different approaches. The closest I got was this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(tmpG = cumsum(c(FALSE, as.logical(diff(event))))) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(tmp = c(0, diff(date)) * !event) %>%
  group_by(tmpG) %>%
  mutate(tae = cumsum(tmp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(tmp, tmpG))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID date       event   tae
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2014-08-03     1     0
2     1 2014-08-04     0     1
3     1 2014-08-07     3     0
4     1 2014-08-10     0     3
5     2 2015-07-01     0     3
6     2 2015-07-03     4     0
7     2 2015-08-01     0    29
```

Any suggestions on how to get that code running (or any other alternative) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach, that uses `fill` to carry forward the most recent event.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(last_event = if_else(event > 0, date, NA_real_)) %>%
  fill(last_event) %>%
  mutate(tae = as.numeric(date - last_event))
```

**Output**

```
     ID date       event last_event   tae
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
1     1 2014-08-03     1 2014-08-03     0
2     1 2014-08-04     0 2014-08-03     1
3     1 2014-08-07     3 2014-08-07     0
4     1 2014-08-10     0 2014-08-07     3
5     2 2015-07-01     0 NA            NA
6     2 2015-07-03     4 2015-07-03     0
7     2 2015-08-01     0 2015-07-03    29
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I'm looking for. However I'm not sure whether the ending "days" will interfere with further data analysis. Is there an elegant way to only have the number of days displayed without "days" at the end?

Comment: @yeshead Try `mutate(tae = as.numeric(date - last_event))` to make this numeric number of days...

Comment: @yeshead See edited answer and update.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(tae = as.double(if_else(event==0, date-lag(date), 0)))
```

Output:

```
     ID date       event   tae
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2014-08-03     1     0
2     1 2014-08-04     0     1
3     1 2014-08-07     3     0
4     1 2014-08-10     0     3
5     2 2015-07-01     0    NA
6     2 2015-07-03     4     0
7     2 2015-08-01     0    29
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that uses only dplyr.

```
df %>%
  mutate(event_id = cumsum(event),
         .by = ID) %>%
  mutate(tae = if_else(event_id == 0L, NA_real_, 
                       as.numeric(date - first(date))), 
         .by = c(ID, event_id))
  ID       date event event_id tae
1  1 2014-08-03     1        1   0
2  1 2014-08-04     0        1   1
3  1 2014-08-07     3        4   0
4  1 2014-08-10     0        4   3
5  2 2015-07-01     0        0  NA
6  2 2015-07-03     4        4   0
7  2 2015-08-01     0        4  29
```